# Passing value from page to Html.ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, html.actionlink

My problem is:

I have two fields, and when i call my @Html.Actionlink method it send a null value for these two parameters.

**This is my page code:**

```
            <div id="new-skill" class="row">
                <label for="Description">Descreva brevemente a sua habilidade:</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.skill.Description, new { @class = "form-control" })

                <label for="Name">Em qual categoria ela está?</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.skill.Category.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })

                <div class="text-center margin-top15">

                    @Html.ActionLink("Adicionar nova habilidade", "InsertNewSkill", new
                                                                                   {
                                                                                       professionalId = ViewBag.professionalId,
                                                                                       skillDescription = "Test Text",
                                                                                       categoryName = Model.skill.Category.Name
                                                                                       }, new 
                                                                                       { 
                                                                                           @class = ""
                                                                                       })
                    </div>

                </div>
```

**This is my InsertNewSkill method:**

```
        public ActionResult InsertNewSkill(int professionalId, string skillDescription, string categoryName)
        {
            initBusinessObjects();

            var professional = professionalBusiness.GetById(professionalId);
            var newSkill = new SkillModel { Description = skillDescription, Category = new SkillCategoryModel { Name = categoryName } };

            skillBusiness.Insert(newSkill);
            professional.Skills.Add(newSkill);

            professionalBusiness.Update(professional);

            return View();
        }
```

What I must to do to achieve this (send the textbox values)?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding the controllerName to your actionLink?

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Adicionar nova habilidade", "InsertNewSkill","CONTROLLER_NAME", new
             {
              professionalId = ViewBag.professionalId,
              skillDescription = "Test Text",
              categoryName = Model.skill.Category.Name
               }, new 
               { 
               @class = ""
               })
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using jQuery / javascript, you should use a form to get those values back to the server.

```
@{using(Html.BeginForm("InsertNewSkill", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Get)){
   <div id="new-skill" class="row">
   <label for="Description">Descreva brevemente a sua habilidade:</label>
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.skill.Description, new { @class = "form-control" })

   <label for="Name">Em qual categoria ela está?</label>
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.skill.Category.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })

   @Html.Hidden("professionalId", ViewBag.professionalId)

   <div class="text-center margin-top15">
         <input type="submit" value="Adicionar nova habilidade"/>

}}
```

With that said, typically you should POST these values back to the server and then redirect to a new ActionMethod (Thus, the acronym PRG for Post, Redirect, Get).

Comment: But I have another button in the same page that post another information :/

Do you have some example to do it using jquery?

Comment: @guisantogui - you can have multiple forms on a single page...it doesn't appear that these fields are captured in your other form.  If it is, then why wouldn't you just handle all of that information (creating skills and whatever else is going on) at the same time?